# Grab multiple elements with the same class name using a JS Variable in GTM

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I want to grab all of these  elements with a GTM variable so that I could send all the product names to Google Analytics whenever a person enters this section of the site.

[Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPOZp.png)

I've tried using the DOM element variable, a JS variable with document.getElementByClassName and document.querySelector and querySelectorAll, however all of these return the value of null. I am not that experienced with JS, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :^)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I made a clone from your picture. You can see there are 3 items on the page.
I use grabNames` function to return an array of these 3 items' names.

So, you can copy `grabNames` function to your GTM custom javascript page.

```js
function grabName() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.name');  // return elements class = name
  var prodctList = [];  // make a new array
  for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i ++) // loop entire elems and push each elem name to the list
    prodctList.push(elems[i].innerText); 
  return prodctList; // return array
}

var arr = grabName();
console.log(arr)
```

```css
.details {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="details">
  <div class="summary">
    <div class="summary__item">
      <a class="name">
        prodct name 1
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="details">
  <div class="summary">
    <div class="summary__item">
      <a class="name">
        prodct name 2
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="details">
  <div class="summary">
    <div class="summary__item">
      <a class="name">
        prodct name 3
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I'm not sure how you wrote your code. any error message?

I think the code below should works

```js
document.getElementByClassName('name');

// or

document.querySelectorAll('.name');
```

You can see these post:

1. [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
2. [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think that the problem is that there are multiple elements with that class and not just one. I need to get the name of all the products on that page and send i to analytics. Any idea on how to grab all the names?

Comment: Try this:
`document.selectorAll('.name').map(item => item.innerText);
`
you can get the product name of all the class name with "name"

Comment: `selectorAll()` return the `Array` and using `map` function to create a new Array with `element.innerText`  
You can learn from these posts
 [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
[Element.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

Comment: Hey, thanks, I tried and this returns a value of undefined unfortunately. Also, when used in GTM, it has an error, because it seems that  this => symbol cannot be used. :(

Comment: Sorry sir, I made a mistake. `querySelector` return Array-like object but there is no `map` function in it. Use this `var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.name');  var prodctList = []; for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i ++) prodcutList.push(elems[i].innerText);` and `productList` is what you want.

Comment: Hey, that is alright :D, you are helping me. GTM tells me that this has to have a function and a return. Do you have any idea what it would look like?

When I try to use this in Console, I still get an undefined value though.

Comment: Okay, maybe I figure out what you want. You're using GTM variable and choose `Custom Javascript` and paste my code, right?  My code doesn't provide a return value that's why GTM shows an error message. And there's a spelling mistake in my code. I will edit my answer for the code you need.

Comment: Yes, I do exactly that. Is there anything I should add or change for it to work with Custom Javascript? OR I should choose a different trigger?